# How can I represent a voronoi diagram?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have some polygons (obstacles) within a rectangle (the borders are obstacles) and I want to find the Voronoi diagram, that means the diagram that shows the lines that have equal distance to two obstacles.

For example (created with [this](http://martin-thoma.com/html5/route-planning/route-planning.htm), please ignore the smiley and the flag):

[image]

The voronoi diagram seems to be not a set of polygons (which would be easy to represent). This one seems to have curves. It was generated by calculating for each pixel the distance to each obstacle.

I have seen [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366), but it has no polygons, but only points.

**How can I represent such a voronoi diagram?**

(By the way, I would also be happy if you had some good articles about this voronoi path planning problem ... I can only find many for points as obstacles.)

Answer (score 7):

You may use the [Voronoi Diagram](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_diagram.htm) implementation from [Boost.Polygon](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm). Maybe if you want your own implementation you can learn looking at the Boost source code.

> The Boost.Polygon library provides implementation of the Voronoi
>   diagram data structure in 2D space. The internal representation
>   consists of the three arrays, that respectively contain: Voronoi cells
>   (represent the area around the input sites bounded by the Voronoi
>   edges), Voronoi vertices (points where three or more Voronoi edges
>   intersect), Voronoi edges (the one dimensional curves containing
>   points equidistant from the two closest input sites). Each of the
>   primitives (cell, vertex, edge) contains pointers to the other linked
>   primitives, so that it's always possible to efficiently traverse
>   Voronoi graph.

There is also this [link](http://www.cescg.org/CESCG99/RCuk/datStr_Vor.htm) with a visual representation from that data structure.

Comment: I would like to understand how this works, so Boost is nice to know, but not an answer. The link you've provided references "Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications" from Mark de Berg. I'll try to get it tomorrow. As soon as I've read and understand the relevant parts, I'll accept your answer. By now, only +1.

Comment: No problem, if you want there is a PDF version. Look at section 3.2: http://www.cescg.org/CESCG99/RCuk/paper.pdf . Good luck.

Comment: There is also this book [1] that I used a long time ago, a chapter about Voronoi Diagrams. 1 - http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Geometry-Cambridge-Theoretical-Computer/dp/0521649765